# how to configure logstash with elasticsearch in window8?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm currently trying to install and run Logstash on Windows 7 using the guidelines of the Logstash website. I am struggling to configure and use logstash with elasticsearch. Created logstash-simple.conf with below content

`

```
enter code here`input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

}

when i execute below Command:

```
 D:\logstash-2.4.0\bin>logstash agent  -f logstash-simple.conf
```

I get following error, i tried many things but i get same error

```
←[31mNo config files found: D:/logstash-2.4.0/bin/logstash-simple.conf
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file? {:level=>:error}←[0m
The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
```

D:\logstash-2.4.0\bin>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `No config files found` in the error. So Logstash can't find the logstash-simple.conf file.

So try

```
D:\logstash-2.4.0\bin>logstash agent  -f [Direct path to the folder containing logstash-simple.conf]logstash-simple.conf
```

Comment: Finally i figured out. The actul extension of the file wasnt .conf instead it was .txt. Now i changed it .. its working now.

Answer (score -1):

Verify if extension is .conf or another other thing like .txt (logstash-simple.conf.txt)